# Firefox display Google Oswald regular font as bold

Tags: css, firefox, fonts, font-face, webfonts

On Firefox, Google Oswald font with font weight set to 400 (or normal) is displayed as bold.

What is strange it works properly on [Google Fonts page](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Oswald), but it fails on live projects.

```
font-family: 'Oswald';
font-weight: 400;
```

Here's the CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zWvVgo?editors=1100

---

I've tested that on Windows 8.1

Firefox 58.0.2 (64-bit)

Chrome 65.0.3325.146 (64-bit)

---

See image below for clarity

[image]

Comment: Works fine in my firefox. You might have a plugin or something?

Comment: No plugins at all. I checked also in private mode - the same effect.

Comment: Strange I run the same version of Firefox too. What is the computed font weight?

Comment: Firefox shows computed value also as 400. I guess it's kind of rendering problem. I wonder why on Google Fonts page font familiy has value "Oswald script=all rev=2" not just simple "Oswald".
Maybe there is some newer version of this font, but perhaps they didn't update it in public api.

Comment: You could try to clear all cache and other garbage

Comment: Do you have a local version of Google Oswald installed? If so, it will take precedence over the webfont version. The weight differences might be explained by that — the desktop version might be older/newer/different from the web version.

Comment: @RoelN that was it. Thank you!

Comment: Review on Safari too and then tell me how it looks on Safari?

Comment: I'm on Windows so no chance to test it on Safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @RoelN I found the issue.

Fonts installed in OS take precedence over webfont versions.
I had installed local version of Google Oswald which behaved slightly different than webfont.